# Output does not include all input for my array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I have this program that is barely started:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Grade 
{
    public:
    string studentID;
    int userChoice = 0;
    int size = 0;
    double* grades = new double[size]{0};
};

void ProgramGreeting(Grade &student);
void ProgramMenu(Grade& student);
string GetID(Grade& student);
int GetChoice(Grade& student);
void GetScores(Grade& student);

int main()
{
    Grade student;
    ProgramGreeting(student);
    ProgramMenu(student);
}

// Specification C1 - Program Greeting function
void ProgramGreeting(Grade &student)
{
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << "Welcome to the GPA Analyzer! " << endl;
    cout << "By: Kate Rainey " << endl;
    cout << "Assignment Due Date: September 25th, 2022 " << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    GetID(student);
    cout << "For Student ID # " << student.studentID << endl;
}

void ProgramMenu(Grade &student)
{
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    cout << setw(25) << "Main Menu" << endl;
    cout << "1. Add Grade " << endl;
    cout << "2. Display All Grades " << endl;
    cout << "3. Process All Grades " << endl;
    cout << "4. Quit Program." << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------------" << endl;
    GetChoice(student);
}

string GetID(Grade &student)
{
    cout << "Enter the student's ID: ";
    cin >> student.studentID;
    if (student.studentID.length() != 8) {
        cout << "Student ID's contain 8 characters ";
        GetID(student);
    }

    return student.studentID;
}

int GetChoice(Grade &student)
{
    cout << "Enter your selection: ";
    cin >> student.userChoice;

    if (student.userChoice == 1) {
        GetScores(student);
    }
    else if (student.userChoice == 2)
    {
    }
    else if (student.userChoice == 2)
    {
    }
    else if (student.userChoice == 4)
    {
        exit(0);
    }
    else 
    {
        cout << "Please enter 1, 2, 3 or 4" << endl;
        GetChoice(student);
    }
}

void GetScores(Grade &student)
{
    int count = 0;
    double score = 0;
    cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter for ID# "
        << student.studentID << "? ";
    cin >> student.size;
    while (count != student.size) {
        cout << "Enter a grade: ";
        cin >> score;
        for (int i = 0; i < student.size; i++) {
            student.grades[i] = score;
        }
        count++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < student.size; i++) {
        cout << student.grades[i] << " ";
    }   
}
```

I am trying to make sure my array is recording all test scores, but when I output the array in my `GetScore` function, each element in the array is the same or equal to the last score I entered. For example, if I choose `3` for size and then enter three values of `99.2 86.4 90.1`, all three elements will read `90.1`.

Why is this happening?

[image: output here]

Comment: Side note: Don't forget to `delete[]` thems arrays!

Comment: Also, a struct is a class where all members are public by default. This can save you from having to write `public:`.

Comment: If all of your functions act on a `Grade` reference, why are they not member functions of the `Grade` class?

Comment: Also, your use of recursion rather than loops when getting valid input is suspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Grade` class is allocating an array of 0 `double` elements (which is *undefined behavior*), and then your `GetScores()` function does not reallocate that array after asking the user how many scores they will enter, so you are writing the input values to invalid memory (which is also *undefined behavior*).

Even if you were managing the array's memory correctly (ie, by using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`), `GetScores()` is also running a `for` loop that writes the user's latest input value into *every* element of the array, instead of just writing it to the *next available* element.  That is why your final output displays only the last value entered in every element.  You need to get rid of that `for` loop completely.

Try something more like this instead (there are several other problems with your code, but I'll leave those as separate exercises for you to figure out):

```
class Grade 
{
    public:
        ...
        int size = 0;
        double* grades = nullptr;
};

...

void GetScores(Grade &student)
{
    int size = 0;
    double score = 0;
    cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter for ID# " << student.studentID << "? ";
    cin >> size;

    if (student.size != size) {
        delete[] student.grades;
        student.grades = new double[size]{0};
        student.size = size;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter a grade: ";
        cin >> score;
        student.grades[i] = score;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << student.grades[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <vector>
...

class Grade 
{
    public:
        ...
        vector<double> grades;
};

...

void GetScores(Grade &student)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    double score = 0;
    cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter for ID# " << student.studentID << "? ";
    cin >> size;

    student.grades.resize(size);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter a grade: ";
        cin >> score;
        student.grades[i] = score;
    }

    /* alternatively:

    student.grades.clear();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << "Enter a grade: ";
        cin >> score;
        student.grades.push_back(score);
    }

    */

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        cout << student.grades[i] << " ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I like vectors a lot more than arrays but my assignment says not to use them. Thank you for the help. I don't know how to "rank" you.

Answer (score -3):

I removed my `for` loop from my `while` loop.

```
void GetScores(Grade &student)
{
    int count = 0;
    double score = 0;
    cout << "How many test scores would you like to enter for ID# "
        << student.studentID << "? ";
    cin >> student.size;
    while (count != student.size) {
        cout << "Enter a grade: ";
        cin >> score;
        student.grades[count] = score;
        
        count++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < student.size; j++) {
        
        cout << student.grades[j] << " ";
    }
    

    
}
```

Comment: A strong answer will explain what the problem was and how the proposed code will fix the problem.

Comment: That change fixes the problem of assigning the correct scores to the correct array elements, but it doesn't address the problem that your array is **invalid to begin with**. `double* grades = new double[size]{0};` is *undefined behavior* when `size` is 0. The array will not grow automatically when `size` is changed. You would have to `delete[]` the existing array and `new[]` a new array. Otherwise, just use `std::vector` instead and let it handle that for you.